# What's the difference between the macros "#define STR(x) #x" and "#define STR(x) VAL(x)" with "#define VAL(x) #x"?

Tags: c

When I use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR(x) #x

int main(void)
{
    printf(__FILE__ STR(__LINE__) "hello!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it prints

```
hello.c__LINE__hello!
```

but when I use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR(x) VAL(x)
#define VAL(x) #x

int main(void)
{
    printf(__FILE__ STR(__LINE__) "hello!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it prints

```
hello.c7hello!
```

what's the difference between

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

and

```
#define STR(x) VAL(x)
#define VAL(x) #x
```

Comment: What if you define VAL(X) first?  Do you get the same results?

Comment: yes,the same with define STR(x) first

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the exact step of macro expanding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742501/whats-the-exact-step-of-macro-expanding)

Comment: See also [How to make a char string from a C macro's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195975).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arguments to macros are themselves macro-expanded, *except* where the macro argument name appears in the macro body with the stringifier # or the token-paster ##.

In the first case, the argument of STR is *not* macro-expanded, and so you just get the name of the LINE macro.

In the second case, the argument of STR *is* macro-expanded when it is substituted into the definition of VAL, and so it works -- you get the actual line number because the LINE macro is expanded.

Answer (score 1):

[C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.10.3.1/1 "Argument substitution":

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
>   argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded
>   by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is
>   replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other
>   preprocessing tokens are available.

So `#` and `##` make arguments be treated differently.