# Weird c++ pre processor behaviour

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Consider the following code:

```
#define M(x) #x
#define M2(x) M(x)

M(VAR);
M2(VAR);
```

With the following command line:
cpp test.cpp -DVAR=xxx

I would expect from the pre-processor to change both M(x) and M2(x)
into "xxx".

But only M2 is replaced. Why is that?

Comment: `#VAR` is `"VAR"`. `M(VAR)` is `#xxx`, which is `"xxx"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283596/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-macros/8283625#8283625

Comment: It should change both. Post the complete program.

Comment: @Mahesh this is the complete program (remmeber that /bin/cpp only run the pre-processor).

Comment: I don't see a way to define macro on Ideone through cmd line. But it seems to [work](http://ideone.com/Di07mo).

Comment: show the output rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: @Mahesh, `-DVAR=xxx` is like `#define VAR xxx`. By the way, Coliru lets you configure the command line, so it's possible there.

Comment: @chris I got that part. If the macro is correctly defined via cmd line, the program should work and both should print `xxx`. Coliru is crashing if I passed `-D` attribute.

Comment: @Mahesh [not really](http://ideone.com/yL2aHB).

Comment: @nm Thanks. Learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 3):

When I try this I get:

```
"VAR";
"abc";
```

(WHICH YOU SHOULD HAVE INCLUDED IN YOUR QUESTION!)

[As this page explains.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

> If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument,
>   you have to use two levels of macros.

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

> s is stringified when it is used in str, so it is not macro-expanded
>   first. But s is an ordinary argument to xstr, so it is completely
>   macro-expanded before xstr itself is expanded. Therefore, by the time
>   str gets to its argument, it has already been macro-expanded.

This happens because of the preprocessor's rules for prescanning macro arguments which are explained [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan):

The important point from that page is:

> Macros that call other macros that stringify or concatenate.
>
> If an argument is stringified or concatenated, the prescan does not
>   occur. If you want to expand a macro, then stringify or concatenate
>   its expansion, you can do that by causing one macro to call another
>   macro that does the stringification or concatenation. For instance, if
>   you have
>
> ```
>       #define AFTERX(x) X_ ## x
>       #define XAFTERX(x) AFTERX(x)
>       #define TABLESIZE 1024
>       #define BUFSIZE TABLESIZE
> ```
>
> AFTERX(BUFSIZE) expands to X_BUFSIZE, and XAFTERX(BUFSIZE) expands to X_1024. (Not to
>   X_TABLESIZE. Prescan always does a complete expansion.)

Comment: Obviously, the question is why is that?

Comment: The short answer is "because that is the way the preprocessor has always worked."  For the long answer read the page I linked to (click on "As this page explains". Don't forget to follow the "Argument Prescan link.)     [I'll edit my answer to include info from that page, too]