# use a value of a preprocessor token to create a new token

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define OOPS 42

#define DEF_FOO(x) void foo_##x(void){ printf(#x" %d\n",x);}

DEF_FOO(ONE);
DEF_FOO(TWO);
DEF_FOO(OOPS);

int main()
{
    foo_ONE();
    foo_TWO();
    foo_OOPS();
    
    return 0;
}
```

gives :

```
ONE 1
TWO 2
OOPS 42
```

I would like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define OOPS 42

#define DEF_BAR(x) void bar_??x??(void){ printf(#x" %d\n",x);}

DEF_BAR(ONE);
DEF_BAR(TWO);
DEF_BAR(OOPS);

int main()
{
    bar_1();
    bar_2();
    bar_42();
    
    return 0;
}
```

gives :

```
ONE 1
TWO 2
OOPS 42
```

or (its does not matter)

```
1 1
2 2
42 42
```

Could I use the value of a token? In theory, preprocessor should know its value, does it?

Comment: hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283596/whats-the-difference-between-the-macros-define-strx-x-and-define-strx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between the macros "#define STR(x) #x" and "#define STR(x) VAL(x)" with "#define VAL(x) #x"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283596/whats-the-difference-between-the-macros-define-strx-x-and-define-strx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need two levels of macros:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define OOPS 42

#define INNER_DEF_BAR(x) void bar_##x(void){ printf(#x" %d\n",x); }
#define DEF_BAR(x) INNER_DEF_BAR(x)

DEF_BAR(ONE);
DEF_BAR(TWO);
DEF_BAR(OOPS);

int main()
{
    bar_1();
    bar_2();
    bar_42();
    
    return 0;
}
```

expands to

```
void bar_1(void){ printf("1"" %d\n",1); };
void bar_2(void){ printf("2"" %d\n",2); };
void bar_42(void){ printf("42"" %d\n",42); };

int main()
{
    bar_1();
    bar_2();
    bar_42();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good answer will explain why a second macro is needed, not just tell somebody to do it.

Answer (score 2):

And the other way to AKX's solution.
It's the same trick but at a different point to give the output:

```
ONE 1
TWO 2
OOPS 42
```

---

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define OOPS 42

#define BAR_NAME(x) bar_##x
#define DEF_BAR(x) void BAR_NAME(x)(void){ printf(#x" %d\n",(x)); }

DEF_BAR(ONE);
DEF_BAR(TWO);
DEF_BAR(OOPS);

int main()
{
    bar_1();
    bar_2();
    bar_42();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The 'trick' here is that undecorated uses of `x` in `DEF_BAR` are substituted but the `#x` isn't. So what is passed the `BAR_NAME` parametric macro is the substitution value of the parameter (1, 2 or 42 as applicable).

PS: I've put `x` in brackets because it's good practice. On the one hand I can't think of a case that would work with the token pasting other than a plain identifier.

PPS: Am I the only one who thinks `##` is better called the token splicing not token pasting operator as is common.

Comment: You can also use `#define CAT(a,b)`, `CAT(bar_,x)`, which it's more reusable.

Comment: @camel-cdr You can but that starts to look like encouraging this sort of shenanigans.