# Concatenate string in C #include filename

Tags: c, macros, include, concatenation, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to concatenate string from another macro when #including a file name (in C). For example,

I have,

```
#define AA 10 
#define BB 20
```

these are parameters that change with program runs

And the file include:

```
#include "file_10_20" // this changes correspondingly i.e. file_AA_BB
```

Is it possible to have something like `#include "file_AA_BB"` somehow? I googled to find that double pound operator can concat strings but couldn't find a way of doing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `#include #(file_##AA##_##BB)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First I thought "that's easy", but it did take a few tries to figure out:

```
#define AA 10 
#define BB 20

#define stringify(x) #x
#define FILE2(a, b) stringify(file_ ## a ## _ ## b)
#define FILE(a, b) FILE2(a, b)

#include FILE(AA, BB)
```

As requested I'll try to explain. `FILE(AA, BB)` expands to `FILE2(AA, BB)` but then `AA` and `BB` is expanded before FILE2, so the next expansion is `FILE2(10, 20)` which expands to `stringify(file_10_20)` which becomes the string.

If you skip FILE2 you'll end up with `stringify(file_AA_BB)` which won't work. The C standard actually spends several pages defining how macro expansion is done. In my experience the best way to think is "if there wasn't enough expansion, add another layer of `define`"

Only stringily will not work because the # is applied before AA is replaced by 10. That's how you usually want it actually, e.g.:

```
#define debugint(x) warnx(#x " = %d", x)
debugint(AA);
```

will print

```
AA = 10
```

Comment: If you are able to explain me why FILE macro is necessary I'll upvote ;-). I've seen many such constructs already and never understood why just 2 macros do not work or even why asael's answer does not work. I am highly interested in knowing how preprocessor works in your example. Can someone explain?

Comment: Don't forget to #undef FILE, because it will collide with something in <stdio.h>

Comment: Right, perhaps not the best choice of macro name.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the details. I am about to try this but before that I am trying to understand rather than just simply using it. I don't understand why there is a need to define FILE and FILE2. You do say that stringify alone will not work - I don't understand why that wont.

Comment: @Per: Thanks for explanation. I think everyone interested in this question would actually like to read http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/cpp_32.html

Comment: @Artur Very useful link. VERY USEFUL. Clears everything nicely.

Comment: In practice this might work for some compilers, but it's not defined in the standard. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20524959/2436175

Comment: Follow-up to @antonio's comment: "The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or a pair of " characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined."

Answer (score 6):

It is usually used like this:

```
#define stringify(x)  #x
#define expand_and_stringify(x) stringify(x)

#define AA 10
#define BB 20

#define TEXT1 "AA = " stringify(AA) " BB = " stringify(BB)
#define TEXT2 "AA = " expand_and_stringify(AA) " BB = " expand_and_stringify(BB)

TEXT1 = "AA = AA BB = BB"
TEXT2 = "AA = 10 BB = 20"
```

It's called **stringification**. You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742619/1168156).

Comment: Isn't this not supposed to work for an include statement? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524491/preprocessor-concatenation-for-include-path/20524959#20524959 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038867/string-concatenation-for-include-path