# How to use a macro in an #include directive?

Tags: c++, macros, include

I'm confused on how to use macros in the `#include` directive. I've done this:

```
#include "../../../../GlobalDefintions.h"
#include "../../../../lib/libc++/" ARCH_FAMILY_S  "/" ARCH_S  "/stkl/printkc/printkc.h"
```

**GlobalDefintions.h**:

```
#ifndef _GlobalDefintions_
#define _GlobalDefintions_

/*Architecture Information Start*/


#define ARCH i386
#define ARCH_FAMILY x86


#define ARCH_S "i386"
#define ARCH_FAMILY_S "x86"

/*Architecture Information End*/

#endif /*_GlobalDefintions_*/
```

But what that gives me is this:

```
kernel.c++:24:88: fatal error: ../../../../lib/libc++/: No such file or directory  

#include "../../../../lib/libc++/" ARCH_FAMILY_S  "/" ARCH_S  "/stkl/printkc/printkc.h"
```

Is there a way to successfully append `ARCH_FAMILY_S` and `ARCH_S` to my `#include` directive string?

Comment: Generally this stuff depends on the compiler, and is very fragile. Instead, control the selection of headers to include via the compiler's header include path option and/or environment variable. E.g. `CPATH` for g++, and `INCLUDE` for Visual C++.

Comment: For concatenation you could define a concatenation macro. But again, it depends on the compiler. I remember really struggling with that until I realized that the general approach, of using macros in include directives, was ungood.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096201/concatenate-string-in-c-include-filename

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i am using Makefiles and since i am writing an operating system i use cross-compilers such as `i686-elf-g++`

Comment: String concatenation occurs after the preprocessor is done.  The preprocessor does not allow those shenanigans.  In my book, you should be specify the directory on the compiler command line and not in the source code.  See also [What are the benefits of a relative path such as `"../include/header.h"` for a header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-relative-path-such-as-include-header-h-for-a-hea)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes i have talked about that with `glauxosdever`in #osdev , but right now i need to solve this problem before moving any further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a series of macros to create your include file. Unfortunately, I can't think of any cleaner (in-source) way of doing this. This works for `arm-eabi-none-gcc` v5.4.1.

```
#define LIBC_DIR ../../../../lib/libc++/

#define STRINGIFY_MACRO(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define CONCAT(n1, n2) STRINGIFY_MACRO(EXPAND(n1)EXPAND(n2))
#define CONCAT5(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) STRINGIFY_MACRO(EXPAND(n1)EXPAND(n2)EXPAND(n3)EXPAND(n4)EXPAND(n5))

// Concatenate the five elements of your path.
// Of course, this can be simplified if there is only a prefix and a suffix
// that needs to be added and the ARCH_FAMILY, /, and ARCH are always present
// in the macro-generated #include directives.
#include CONCAT5(LIBC_DIR,ARCH_FAMILY,/,ARCH,/stkl/printkc/printkc.h)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works. The message I get is fatal error: ../../../../lib/libc++/\"x86\" /\"i386\" /stkl/printkc/printkc.h: No such file or directory, which looks strangely formatted

Comment: `kernel.c++:32:78: fatal error: ../../../../lib/libc++/\"x86\" /\"i386\" /stkl/printkc/printkc.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry... you need to use `ARCH` and `ARCH_FAMILY` instead of the `_S`-suffixed versions. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also, to save yourself the possibility of forgetting to update `ARCH_S` and `ARCH` together (and similarly, for family), you can use the `STR` macro I provided to define `ARCH_S` as `STR(ARCH)`.

Comment: Now it's fatal error: ../../../../lib/libc++/x86 /1 /stkl/printkc/printkc.h: No such file or directory

Comment: That's weird... are you sure the `ARCH` variable is set correctly? The `/1` seems to have come out of nowhere. At least the `x86` part seems to have pasted correctly, so it looks like we're on the right track for your compiler.

Comment: It works now.. You just had to not have spaces when using include directive `#include CONCAT5(LIBC_DIR,ARCH_FAMILY,/,ARCH,/stkl/printkc/printkc.h)`

Comment: @AndyG the space.. `, ARCH_FAMILY` . Try to get rid of those spaces and it should work!

Comment: @AndyG, it looks like the compiler used on ideone converts `i386` into the number 1. I'm not sure what feature of C/C++ that is, though. You can verify this at http://ideone.com/BkNrHm