# Wrapping #include directive into macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I need a special include file (in essence a very log list of names) included in the middle of my code (and I cannot make a list a part of any structure). It works but it looks ugly:

```
    <code>;
#include <big_list.inc>
    <more-code>;
```

Is it possible to define some macro to include this file, I feel that this would look better.

```
#define BIG_LIST_INC() ...

    <code>;
    BIT_LIST_INC();
    <more_code>;
```

Comment: You might also consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062883/how-to-use-a-macro-in-an-include-directive)

Comment: I would rather put a comment next to it. Hiding the `#include` behind just another macro doesnt make it easier to read imho

Comment: Put it into another file, and include this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the contents of your include file to :

```
#define BIG_LIST_INC ...
```

where `...` is the current content of the file (if it spans multiple lines, don't forget to end lines with `\`).

Then include the file at the top of your source file, and the big list can be inserted in the code using `BIG_LIST_INC` :

```
#include "big_list.h"

// <code>
BIG_LIST_INC
// <more_code>
```

Comment: It seems to me that in this case all big list definitions will be on one line after preprocessor run, the list is big I am afraid to blow limit on the line length. It will be perfect solution if list items will be placed on separate line

Comment: @zzz777 : as mentioned in the answer, macro's can span multiple lines with the use of the \ line break character

Comment: As far as I understand after the preprocessing the whole list will be on one line.

Comment: @zzz777 : ah, you're talking about the logical source line limit. Unless you actually run into an issue with that, I wouldn't worry about it. [gcc eg. imposes no such limit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-limits.html), and I'm sure most popular compilers don't either (check your compiler documentation to confirm).

Answer (score 0):

It might perhaps be an option to replace this with 3 include directives

```
#include "pre_macro_stuff.h"  
#include <big_list.inc>  
#include "post_macro_stuff.h"
```

Where pre_macro_stuff.h and post_macro_stuff.h contains the macros.