# STRINGIFY in .cpp file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, s-function

I am reading some .cpp files made to compile them and have a mex file to use in MATLAB for a Level-2 S-Function.

I would like to know what is this instruction IN PRACTICE for:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question. The suggested duplicate is about how the macro expansion works, while the question here refers to use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, it can be useful in macros like [asserts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/). In case the assert fails, you may not only want to know *that* something failed, but also *what* failed. Then you can create a string about the condition that actually didn't hold. Then you can use it to print an error message to the console or use it as description in an exception object.

EDIT: In case you were wondering more about why there are *two* macros doing the same thing, one just referring to the other, you can find the answer in the the [question referred to by Piotr S. in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742501/whats-the-exact-step-of-macro-expanding).